# Get name of inheriting class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

In the below mockup, how do I find out, if I am an instance of FooDAL or WeeDAL from within the method DoMagix()?

```
Public MustInherit Class DataAccessClass
    Public Sub DoMagix()
        '** LOOK AT ME!!! **
        'Who am I? Why am I here? Where am I going? 
        '** /LOOK AT ME!!! **
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FooDAL
   Inherits DataAccessClass
End Class

Public Class WeeDAL
   Inherits DataAccessClass
End Class
```

My OO-skills are teh suck, so if I get the terminology wrong, please slap me and set me straigth (in that order plz).

Comment: Just a query, I've always thought that the base getting to know its derived classes was always bad design practice. So is this really the only way you wish to do this?

Comment: I knew that would come up, and I am sure there is a better way of doing this. I am using it while playing around with my own little ORM-tool, and I make some assumptions about the database based on the name of the derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Timespace traveller" wrote the answer in a comment:

I think Overridable is not necessary; however, it should use Me.GetType(), which is polymorphic, and should get the correct type even with DoMagix not set as Overridable.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First the DoMagix should be "Overridable".</strike>

And you can use GetType(Me) inside DoMagix to know what type it is at runtime.

Comment: I think Overridable is not necessary; however, it should use Me.GetType(), which is polymorphic, and should get the correct type even with DoMagix not set as Overridable.

Comment: You should make this an answer, Timespace Traveller. :)

Answer (score 0):

hope I can "reanimate" this topic. I ran into similar problem, except I need a shared property to return the child name... So the Me... Construct won't work.
I know, this is considered as bad design, but I had no better idea - except a bunch of repeated code...
My goal is very similar to the OP's one...How do get  the "A" into base Class' XString Property WITHOUT instancinatig...?
(xd is a XMLDocument...)

```
Public MustInherit Class MinMax

    Protected Shared Property XString As String = ???

    Public Shared Function isValid(value As String) As Boolean
        Return min <= value <= max
    End Function

    Private Shared ReadOnly Property min As Double
        Get
            Return xd.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("FOEB/Restrictions/{0}", XString)).InnerText.Split("..")(0)
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Shared ReadOnly Property max As Double
        Get
            Return xd.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("FOEB/Restrictions/{0}", XString)).InnerText.Split("..")(1)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Class Usage:

```
Public Class Restrictions
    Public Class A
        Inherits MinMax
    End Class
    Public Class B
        Inherits MinMax
    End Class

End Class


dim isOk as Boolean= Restrictions.A.isValid("10")
```

The correstonding XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FOEB>
  <Restrictions>
    <A>1..21</A>
  </Restrictions>
</FOEB>
```

So the return Value should be TRUE

Xstring is protected, because I tried to shadow/override in the child - no luck, so it's actually not relevant in this way

Comment: Please create a new, separate question. You are also much more likely to get an answer. :)